# CSV file is not downloading

Tags: php

I am trying to export few data in CSV file. Though the file is successfully written but it is not downloading instead is being read by browser. `$csvarray` is data array and `fputcsv2` is function similar to PHP default `fputcsv` function

```
$output =  fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
rewind( $output );
foreach($csvarray as $product) {
    fputcsv2($output, $product,',',' ');
}
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');

readfile ($output);   
exit();
```

Comment: the file name should not be quoted

Comment: Shouldn't headers go first ? What does F12/network in your browser show as headers ?

Comment: I've tried removing quote on th file name and moving header first, but the file is still not downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the issue got resolved, may be helpful for somebody,

when I generate the data array before dumping it into the CSV file I printed array using `$print_r` with `<pre> ... </pre>` tag. though I remove `$print_r` but `<pre> ... </pre>` tag was still there preventing file to download. As soon as I remove this tag file is now downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

First example in the readfile() documentation should help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

**Example #1 Forcing a download using readfile()**

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```